# Exporting merged layers so coordinates are in the same CRS using QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, export

I have two different data point sets, one with Easting/Northings, one with Latitude/Longitude. I can display them on one map and also merge the layers in QGIS 3 (3.4.4) just fine. However, when I export the merged layer as CSV-file, the coordinates are still either East/North or Lat/Long.

How do I get all of them in the same format (East/North or all Lat/Long)?

Comment: How are you merging them?

Answer (score 6):

1. Use [Reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#reproject-layer) tool to conver the layers into a single CRS.
2. Merge reprojected layers with the [Merge](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#merge-vector-layers) tool.
3. Export merged layers as a CSV-file.